# Creating and filling an array

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

I am trying to create an array populated with values between 'x' and 'y' at specified increment z.

I have tried to 'translate' the code from Matlab as

```
b<-(0.7:0.1:1.2)
```

but this just returns a single value -> 0.7

Ideally I would have liked the code to return the array [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`seq()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/seq)?

```
b <- seq(from = 0.7, to = 1.2, by = 0.1)
```